# C# and C++ class inheritance intermingling

Tags: c#, inheritance, c++-cli

I have an interesting stack of assemblies I want to put together:

1. Common Assembly (C# or C++-CLI)

   ```
   public class MyBase
   {
   public void MethodA()
   { ... }
   private void MethodB()
   { ... }
   protected virtual MethodC()
   { ... }
   }
   ```
2. Test Code Assemblies (all C++-CLI)

   ```
   public class MySpecific : public MyBase{
   protected: override MethodC();
   };
   ```
3. Test Simulator (C#)

   ```
   MySpecific obj = new MySpecific();
   obj.MethodC();
   ```

While assembly 1 could be C++-CLI to keep things simpler, I'd really like to keep assembly 3 in C#.  This is largely an exercise to see if inheritance could be done in either direction, but I also have a real-world case where this stack is useful.

The first problem I find is that the C++-CLI assembly does not compile because it doesn't recognize MyBase as a class, even though I have a reference to assembly 1 and what looks like the proper namespace.

How do I write classes that are language-portable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to declare MySpecific as a managed class like this:

```
public ref class MySpecific : public MyBase { ... }
```

See the CLI/C++ documentation for details. You will not be able to use old C++ code without modifications, but I think everything you have in mind should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

```
`#using "..\common\bin\debug\common.dll"`
```

That, in addition to the /clr switch (the c++ side needs to be mananged) seems to be working, so far.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine, but you'll need to use the C++/CLI syntax, if you're working with managed types (ie: inheriting from a C# class).  So, in this case, the item in 2. should look more like:

```
public ref class MySpecific : public MyBase { ... }
```

Make sure that file is compiled with /clr are well.

Here is a [tutorial describing inheritance in C++/CLI](http://www.functionx.com/cppcli/classes2/Lesson07b.htm).

Comment: How can I get the C++ compiler to see MyBase?  I keep getting "C2504: 'Mybase' : base class undefined"

Comment: Make sure it's added as a reference, and that you have this file compiled with /clr.  Also, make sure you're working with (or using) the appropriate namespaces.  It sounds like you're not in a section using the same namespace.  You could fully qualify MyBase - ie:  public ref class MySpecific : public MyNamespace::MyBase { ... }