# Extending C# classes in c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, inheritance

I have a project mainly written in C#. Now, due to some limitations of an external library I need to incorporate some C++ code, defined in a separate project.

Is it possible to create a C++ class, in a Visual Studio c++\cli library, that extends a C# class defined in a separate DLL lib?

Basically, I need to share some code defined in an abstract C# class in a new C++ class using inheritance.

Comment: If your C++ class is actually a managed .net class, why would you think that you *couldn't* do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# and C++ class inheritance intermingling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278893/c-sharp-and-c-class-inheritance-intermingling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend a C# class in a C++ project implementing a ref class child, defined in a /clr compiled source like this:

> public ref class CPPRefClass: public CSharpClass

That of course means that CPPRefClass is still a .NET class, but you can utilize it in a pure C++ class using delegation.

You can even define it as a member of a C++ native class using **gcroot** template:

```
class NativeClass
{
private:
   gcroot<CPPRefClass^> m_CPPRefClass;

}
```

Here is another example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aeb4be4k